# CFAdmin keeps on kicking back to login screen

Tags: coldfusion

We just got a new CF 10 VPS with Hostek.  All seems well but in cfadmin we keep on kicked back to the login screen. I know that [you can't have more than one user logged in at a time](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/6/13/cf10_admin_allows_one_logon_at_a_time/) but even with just one user, it keeps on kicking us out.  We're not doing any particular action (ex. posting a form) when this occurs.  It seems to be randomly occurring after a few clicks here and there.  In the blog I linked to, some in the comments were having this problem too but there isn't a solution posted.

Thanks

Comment: I remember a cookies issue in Internet Explorer when sub-domains include a dash (-).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a cookies issue.  Check your cookies settings and make sure your browser is accepting cookies from that domain.

Answer (score 1):

For us the problem goes away when we access ColdFusion administrator using a numeric IP address (eg `https://1.2.3.4/CFIDE/administrator` instead of `https://example.com/CFIDE/administrator`).

But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities.

- As other have suggested you might be having trouble with cookies. But if this were the case I would sort of expect that you would not be able to log in at all.
- Your assumption that only 1 login at a time is a possibility. Check the server admin logs to see if that is true.
- Your Cf server might be restarting. A restart would kill your session causing you to have to login again. Check the event logs, the out logs and the runtime/bin directory (where you will see hot spot errors).
- Your default session timeout might be set to draconian levels. The default is typically 20 minutes, but if someone has changed it to (for example) 2 minutes you would get logged out any time you took too long to click on something.

That's all I can think of :)

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestions, unfortunately nothing helped.  I'm sure it's only one user logged in at a time

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this (since posting back in 2012)? Either way, I'll offer some thoughts in case others may find the question and still seek an answer.

Thanks for the link to my blog post, btw. Sorry it didn't help then.

You refer to other comments reflecting the problem with no solution. Did you happen to revisit the comments since then? You may find new info.

In addition, did you happen to have more than one browser open looking at the Admin? That could cause the problem (as each browser creates different cookies to track the "user" who is logged in).

Or did you happen to have more than once instance of CF against which you were logging in, but using perhaps the same IP address (but different ports) for their CF Admin? That would cause even one browser to send the same cookies to the different instances, which may cause the instance to reject/rotate them to protect against session fixation.

Indeed, to that point, did you ever try using the coldfusion.session.protectfixation jvm flag to see if that helped (https://www.petefreitag.com/item/815.cfm), though it may be overkill to solve this one problem.

FInally, did you happen to see the later post I did, which showed how some problems are due to duplicate cookies? (http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2014/4/10/CF_Admin_error_about_error_accessing_this_page)